# Error on try to free memory from a Binary Tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference, free

I try to free the memory recursive, and when I try to display to tree, to show a message that the tree has been freed.
The code for the delete is

```
void stergereArbore(ArboreBin*rad) {
    if (rad) {
        stergereArbore(rad->st);
        stergereArbore(rad->dr);
        free(rad->avion.model);
        free(rad->avion.preturi);
        free(rad);
    }
}
```

and for display is

```
void afisareSRD(ArboreBin*a) {
    if (a) {
        afisareSRD(a->st);
        afisareAvion(a->avion);
        afisareSRD(a->dr);
    }
    else {
        printf("Empty");
    }
}
```

and the error message. I`m kind of new to data structures, and maybe I misspelled something.
[image]

Comment: Could you show how you are calling `afisareSRD` and `stergereArbore`?

Comment: The problem is probably not in the shown code, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function deals with a copy of the head pointer of the tree. So changing of the copy does not influence on the original head pointer of the tree.

Either you should pass the head pointer by reference to the function or you should return the pointer to the head from the function that the caller could set it to NULL.

Here are two approaches

```
void stergereArbore( ArboreBin **rad ) 
{
    if ( *rad ) 
    {
        stergereArbore( &( *rad )->st );
        stergereArbore( &( *rad )->dr );
        free( *rad );
        *rad = NULL;
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
ArboreBin *rad = NULL;

//...

stergereArbore( &rad );
```

Or

```
ArboreBin * stergereArbore( ArboreBin *rad ) 
{
    if ( rad ) 
    {
        rad->st = stergereArbore( rad->st );
        rad->dr = stergereArbore( rad->dr );
        free( rad );
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
ArboreBin *rad = NULL;

//...

rad = stergereArbore( rad );
```